# Can the quest "Setup" be completed using the new MP-155 shotgun?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

After successfully hiding the lure involving *false flash drive* in Dorms, Skier sends us on a new quest called [Setup](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Setup) asking us to

> dress up like one of them (Scav vest, Ushanka, and MP-153/133 shotgun) and smoke PMCs

While this does not mention recently added [Izhmekh MP-155](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/MP-155_12ga_semi-automatic_shotgun), the description of that weapon implies it is the direct successor of the mentioned MP-153. Does that make it a valid choice for the quest, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, any of those three (MP-133, MP-153 or MP-155) will work.** Just tried it, was counted.

[image: Skiers quest "Setup" with progress 1 out of 15]

Comment: The additionally added double-barrel shotgun *MP-43-1C* is now also reported to work, and the quest description has been updated to clarify any *MP-series* qualifies.